# Ruby Hpricot XML Parsing ARIN document

Tags: ruby, xml, hpricot

I am trying to parse this ARIN xml document. I want to get the "name" attribute inside the orgRef tag, and it's not doing what I expected when I parse it with Hpricot

```
<?xml version='1.0'?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='http://whois.arin.net/xsl/website.xsl' ?><nets xmlns="http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/core/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/rdns/v1" termsOfUse="https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html"><limitExceeded limit="256">false</limitExceeded><net termsOfUse="https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html"><registrationDate>1998-04-18T00:00:00-04:00</registrationDate><ref>http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-205-188-0-0-1</ref><ns2:delegations termsOfUse="https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html"><ns2:delegationRef name="188.205.in-addr.arpa.">http://whois.arin.net/rest/rdns/188.205.in-addr.arpa.</ns2:delegationRef></ns2:delegations><endAddress>205.188.255.255</endAddress><handle>NET-205-188-0-0-1</handle><name>AOL-DTC</name><netBlocks><netBlock><cidrLength>16</cidrLength><endAddress>205.188.255.255</endAddress><description>Direct Assignment</description><type>DS</type><startAddress>205.188.0.0</startAddress></netBlock></netBlocks><pocs termsOfUse="https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html"><pocLinkRef handle="AOL-NOC-ARIN" function="T" description="Tech">http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/AOL-NOC-ARIN</pocLinkRef></pocs><orgRef name="America Online, Inc" handle="AMERIC-59">http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/AMERIC-59</orgRef><parentNetRef name="NET205" handle="NET-205-0-0-0-0">http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-205-0-0-0-0</parentNetRef><startAddress>205.188.0.0</startAddress><updateDate>1998-04-27T00:00:00-04:00</updateDate><version>4</version></net></nets>
```

I am doing this:

```
doc = Hpricot(contents)
(doc/:orgRef).each do |orefRef|
    puts  "FOUND ELEMENT!"   
end
```

When I do (doc/:net), it is outputting something, but for some reason it can't find that single element. Any ideas. I try (doc/:net/orgRef) as well. What's up? Did ARIN purposely made this XML impossible to parse?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into Nokogiri as a replacement to Hpricot, it should be a drop-in after changing your initialization to `doc = Nokogiri::XML(contents)`. It's very robust and well supported. Hpricot has had some problems parsing XML when I've used it, including totally crashing. I've never had problems like that with Nokogiri.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to use Nokogiri at first but had trouble installing it in my Mac. Weird dependency issues involving the architecture.

Comment: I use it on two Macs and several Linux boxes running different distros without problems. Feel free to create a new question and we'll see if we can help figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I got it. I had to do ipWebHost =  (doc/"net/orgRef")[0]['name']